# Meteor+React Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have an app that is made in Meteor with React, on a desktop browser the application runs fine no warnings, but when I try to run the app in a mobile device i'm getting these errors that prevent the application to start and I just can't figure out where is the problem.

I'm getting this error on the console, on a couple of files:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

always on line 1, referencing `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
...
```

Comment: I guess you misconfigured some routes. This often occours if a default html file is returned from the webserver if it doesn't find the correct resource (often *.js files). So check, if you expect an HTML or a Javascript file on a specific URL

Comment: yep. a javascript file is expected, but what I find odd, is the problem just happen on mobile browsers.

Comment: what do you mean by "on a couple of files"? Are you serving static files from meteor? or do you mean routes? If so, what router are you using, and what does your main.html look like?